# Can't .append() option to select

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

I have a problem with .append() function. 
I created a `<select/>` element in jquery, and I'm appending it to many table rows, with (sample classes):

```
var $select = $('<select class="my-select" ><option></option></select>');
$('‪#‎mytable‬ tr.first_row td.first_cell').append($select.clone());
$('‪#‎mytable‬ tr.second_row td.first_cell').append($select.clone());
```

then, I want to add a new `<option/>` to that select, so I do like this:

```
var new_option = $('<option/>').val('value').text('text');
$('.my-select').append(new_option); //works
$select.append(new_option); //doesn't work
```

Everything works fine, the select is added to any table row, and the new_option is appended to any of those `<select>`, but I can't append it to the $select element.... I tried in many ways but it seems impossible...
I also tried:

```
$select.find('option:last').after(new_option); //doesn't work
$select.find('option:last').before(new_option); //doesn't work
new_option.appendTo($select); //doesn't work
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/4/

Anyone has any idea why this should not work? It looks like something extremely easy, but I can't sort this problem out, I hope someone can help me understand what's going on..

Comment: Use string instead of jQuery object, `var $select = '<select class="my-select" ><option></option></select>';
$('‪#‎mytable‬ tr.first_row td.first_cell').append($select);
$('‪#‎mytable‬ tr.second_row td.first_cell').append($select);`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `$select` is not modified in any way between the two lines of code?

Comment: Yes Frederic. $select is never modified except for appending new options..

Comment: You are appending cloned element of $select, not $select itself, then you append option to $select, not cloned element

Comment: With this `$('.my-select').append(new_option);` I add the new option to elements on the DOM, and it works. I can't append the new option to the dynamic element I'm holding in jquery.

Comment: @Yuri _" I can't append the new option to the dynamic element I'm holding in jquery. "_ See post

Comment: @Yuri if you check in console, you would see the option is added to $select, just that this element isn't part of DOM. Keep ref on cloned element,  see guest's answer. Now regarding your last comment, im quite confused what is your expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff, I would expect seing the new appended option if I console.log($select) after .append(new_option)...at least. But this doesn't happen, nor future appended selects have new_options

Comment: The phrase, ***does not work***, usually makes sense when accompanied by **expected behavior** (thanks @A.Wolff) and **actual behavior**. Right now none of us really knows what your issue is. :-(

Comment: @Yuri `.append()` removes element from `DOM` and places it in element `.append()` called on. To use `.append(clone)` multiple times on different elements call `.clone()` on variable `clone` , e.g., `$(element1).append(clone)` , `$(element2).append(clone.clone())`

Comment: @Yuri not sure how do you check it but your observation is wrong as i understand it

Comment: Works fine when you [**append to the DOM**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ep4v55dz/). I can see now how the confusion is coming -- look at the console output **Firebug Lite**; it can be misleading. But if you look at your [**browser's console output**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ep4v55dz/1/), it's all there - `<select class="my-select"><option></option><option value="value">text</option></select>`.

Comment: @PeterKA thx, i would had never think about checking using firebug lite and ya could explain OP observation

Comment: Here you can see what I mean. Check the console when adding row and option http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/3/

Comment: Again append() moves element, here option. Im currently on tablet so im sorry but it is hard for me to update jsfiddle

Comment: So sound like you are thinking that each time you call append() a copy of appended element is added but in fact same element is added meaning if you appended previously inside other element, then the appended element is removed from it. Sorry if this is quite unclear

Comment: That's why I use .append($select.clone()); Am I using it wrongly?

Comment: This is what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/7/ sorry for the alert but easier for me on tablet and anyway most broser console update object on the fly so

Comment: New Page here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350072/cant-append-option-to-select-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `option` element just created and added to `$select` is being removed and added to `.my-select` elements on the DOM. To avoid that, add a clone to `$select` as suggested below.

Just change:

```
$select.append(option);
```

To:

```
$select.append(option.clone());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/v15zyzxj/8/)

Comment: The new_option is created locally inside .on() listener, do I still need to append a clone?

Comment: Yes, you need to. It actually does not matter if it's local or global. See the updated demo & @guest271314's comment under the question.

Comment: Please answer here. Your answer is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350072/cant-append-option-to-select-element

Comment: Thanks @Yuri; just did. Looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Going to delete this messy question

Answer (score 1):

Appear to append at stacksnippets

```js
var $select = $('<select class="my-select" ><option></option></select>');
// define variable `clone`
var clone = $select.clone();
var new_option = $('<option/>').val('value').text('text');
$select.append(new_option); 

$("body").append($select);

var new_option2 = $('<option/>').val('value').text('text2');
clone.append(new_option2);
$("table tr").append(clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in the case I have to append the clone to 2 different rows http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/

Comment: @Yuri `.append()` removes element from `DOM` and places it in element `.append()` called on . Try cloning `.clone` at `.second` `$("table tr.second td").append(clone.clone());` http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/1/

Comment: I made a pretty compelte fiddle where you can see my same error. What I'm doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/2/

Comment: @Yuri _"made a pretty compelte fiddle where you can see my same error. What I'm doing wrong?"_ What is "error" ? Appear to return expected results at http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/2/ ? If click `"ADD ROW"` a new `tr` is appended . If click `"ADD OPTION"` `option` elements are appended to the `select` at most recently appended `tr`

Comment: then, try adding new row after having added a option.

Comment: @Yuri _"then, try adding new row after having added a option"_ Yes ? Not certain what expected result is ? Perhaps beyond scope of original Question ? Try creating new Question including `html` , `js` at jsfiddle , ask specific Question as to that process ?

Comment: New question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350072/cant-append-option-to-select-element

Comment: No. I had to .clone() the new option.

Comment: @Yuri _"had to .clone() the new option. "_ Yes, see post at `var clone = $select.clone();` , comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348582/cant-append-option-to-select/33348854?noredirect=1#comment54493749_33348854 .

Comment: I had to clone the new option, not the select. I only need to clone the select when appending it. But if I have to append an option to both $select and DOM elements, I have to .append(new_option.clone())