# Can't .append() option to select element

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

I have a problem with .append() function.

```
$('#add_row').on('click', function(){
    var new_row = $(row_default).clone();
    new_row.find('.col-1').text($(this).find('.ass-col-partenza').text());
    new_row.find('.col-2').text($(this).find('.ass-col-colore').text());
    new_row.find('.col-3').empty().html($select.clone());
    $table.append(new_row);
    console.log('New row added with select: ', $select);
});

$('#add_option').on('click', function(){
    var option = $('<option/>').val('Value '+idx).text('Text '+idx);
    idx++;
    // This should add options, and they should be added to DOM in future .append()
    $select.append(option);
    $('#my_table').find('.my_select').append(option);
    console.log('Added new option, new select is: ',$select);
});
```

Here is the fiddle with a short instruction list:
http://jsfiddle.net/v15zyzxj/5/

I would expect that if I append an option, this is shown if I append a new row.

PS I deleted my previous question because it was getting pretty messy.

Comment: Append clone of option otherwise you are just moving it

Comment: Just tried and it works. Thanks! Now I get what you mean with "otherwise you are just moving it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new `option` element just created and added to `$select` is being removed and added to `.my-select` elements on the DOM. To avoid that, add a clone to `$select` as suggested below.

Just change:

```
$select.append(option);
```

To:

```
$select.append(option.clone());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/v15zyzxj/8/)

Alternatively you could use `.add()` to combine all elements (in DOM or memory) that you want to append the new `option` to and then just `.append()` without the need to `.clone()`:

```
//$select.append(option);
$('#my_table').find('.my_select').add($select).append(option);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/v15zyzxj/9/)